# getting first day and last day of a quarter and 2 quarters back for a date

Tags: sql, date, hive, hiveql

how to get first day and last day of a quarter for a date?
and also first day and last day of 2 quarters back for a date in **Hive** or sql

for example for Feb 03 2014 first day and last day of the quarter will be
Jan 01 2014 and Mar 31 2014
 and for the same date first and last day of 2 quarters back will be Jul 01 2013 and Sep 31 2013

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in the following way (not too fancy, but there is no direct way). To make it simpler, I just concatenated both output dates

```
-- before Hive 1.3
select 
case 
when ceil(month(mydate)/ 3.0) =  1 then concat("Jan 01 ",year(mydate),"|","Mar 31 ",year(mydate))
when ceil(month(mydate)/ 3.0)  =  2 then then concat("Apr 01 ",year(mydate),"|","Jun 30 ",year(mydate))
when ceil(month(mydate)/ 3.0)  =  3 then then concat("Jul 01 ",year(mydate),"|","Sep 30 ",year(mydate))
when ceil(month(mydate)/ 3.0)  =  4 then then concat("Oct 01 ",year(mydate),"|","Dec 31 ",year(mydate))
else
null
end,
ceil(month(mydate)) as quarter

from (
    select 
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('Feb 03 2014' , 'MMM dd yyyy')) as mydate
) t;


--Hive 1.3 or higher

select 
case 
when quarter(mydate) =  1 then concat("Jan 01 ",year(mydate),"|","Mar 31 ",year(mydate))
when quarter(mydate)  =  2 then then concat("Apr 01 ",year(mydate),"|","Jun 30 ",year(mydate))
when quarter(mydate)  =  3 then then concat("Jul 01 ",year(mydate),"|","Sep 30 ",year(mydate))
when quarter(mydate)  =  4 then then concat("Oct 01 ",year(mydate),"|","Dec 31 ",year(mydate))
else
null
end,
ceil(month(mydate)) as quarter

from (
    select 
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('Feb 03 2014' , 'MMM dd yyyy')) as mydate
) t;
```

just replace the hardcoded date for your column in the select in the inner query

Comment: `select 
to_date(
concat(year(`_c0`),"-",1+3*(quarter(`_c0`)-1),"-01"))
from (
    select CURRENT_DATE()
    ) as asdf
    ;`
Apache Hive (version 2.3.2)

Comment: and start of semester
`select

                to_date(
                concat(
                    YEAR(`_c0`),
                    "-0",
                    CASE WHEN QUARTER(`_c0`) IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 7 END,
                    "-01"
                    ))
                    from (
    select CURRENT_DATE()
    ) as asdf
                    ;`